# Hudson and SVN repo

Tags: svn, scripting, zip, hudson

I am using [hudson](/questions/tagged/hudson) as my [continuous-integration](/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) tool. I need to download a single zip file from my subversion repository

When I run `svn co`, this gives me the following error ...

`/somedir/*.zip  refers to a file, not a directory`

Is it not possible to check out a zip file?

Once that is done I would like to run a script that extracts it and sets up a directory structure.

Downloading a zip file is a very strong requirement that cannot be worked around.

Comment: Subversion doesn't let you check out a single file: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#single-file-checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As several people already mentioned you can't check out a single file from subversion. It also does not make sense to put a zip file into subversion in the first place. That would be like putting a binary into subversion.

However, there are at least two things that might help you.

1. For triggering the build, go to the advanced settings for subversion in your job and put your zip name into the *include region* option. This way your build will be triggered only if the zip changed.
2. use the [M2 Extra Steps Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin) for extra build steps before and after the main build step for a maven job. This way you can create a before step (*execute shell* for Linux or *execute Windows batch command*) to extract your zip.

Comment: Thanks for the help that fixed the issue. :) or least gives me options to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your refer to the folder containing the zip in your Hudson setup? After that trigger a script or Maven goal or Ant task that does the unzipping etc.

Instead of checking out the zip file checkout the folder containing the zip file. Configure a Build in Hudson which checkouts your folder and triggers a script.

See the "Shell Scripts and Windows Batch Commands" part of the following document : http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project

Comment: so no way to check out a *.zip file?

Comment: There is a way to checkout a zip file like I described it, but I guess not to treat the remote zip file as an alias to your project.

Comment: can you explain the trigger a script part?

Comment: @garbagecollector, did you fix your issues?